# How to Include Add'l .js from an ASP.NET MVC View? (.aspx)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm using views (the .aspx kind) in conjunction with a Master Page in an ASP.NET MVC 2.0 application.

I'm unclear on how to include an additional Javascript file as part of a specific .aspx view.  I get an error message about what I can include in the content tags on the child page.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your javascript file in Site.Master page,or .aspx Content tags!
It works just fine!
like this :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server"> 
    Search 
     //Write here
</asp:Content>  
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server"> 
     <script type="text/javascript">
      //Write here
     </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: For inline script, that does work - but I'm trying to include a standalone .js file:

<script src="../../Content/jquery.tools.min.js">

When the page renders, I get this error: "Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls."

Comment: I had success with this: I added another special Content control inside the HEAD element of the Master Page.  Then I could refer to it from child pages like this, adding new script includes:

<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
  <script src="http://mydomain.com/myscriptfile.js" type="javascript" />
</asp:Content>

Comment: Sorry about that!
1:You can add new script in "MainContent" !
2:You can add a new ContentPlaceHolder in master page ,then you can add new script in here! 
Make sure your scripts'path is right!@blaster